# GridbagLayout within ScrollPane Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I'd just made a layout in GridBagLayout for a split pane. 
Worked perfectly and looked right.

I then needed to then add a scroll bar vertically only. Hence I have done that now.
However the layout doesn't 'size' like before.
It now stretches across rather sticking to the area of the pane shown.

```
JSplitPane VPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,(new class1()),new JScrollPane(new class2(),ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));
```

I need to make it look like it did before. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) I hate hazarding guesses like this

Comment: Hi =D 
I've posted the code that effectively 'ruined' my gridbag layout.
Not really sure what else to post?

Comment: @user1203297 : Exactly what effect is brought with the addition of this line and how it looked like before the addition, is something that no one will be able to imagine, or  portrait out of intuition. That's why the need of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you've done is "hide" the horizontal scroll bar.  This will have no effect on the view port that is managing your component.

Try wrapping your existing layout in a `Scrollable` interface.  If you don't want to implement one your self, you could use a wrapper container instead...

```
public class ScrollableWrapper extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    private Component wrapper;

    public ScrollableWrapper(Component wrapper) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(wrapper);
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return wrapper.getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 64;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 64;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then, we you add it to your scroll pane...

```
JSplitPane VPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,new class1(),new JScrollPane(new ScrollableWrapper(class2())));
```